# How to represent the span between two different times .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am constructing an alarm clock via .net. I want to display via percentage (Progressbar) how soon the alarm is close to triggering.. I currently have a function that gives me a countdown from the alarm time and the current system time that returns the hours, minutes and seconds but I have not been able to figure this out..

```
Dim span As System.TimeSpan = TimeEnd.TimeOfDay - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
Dim remaining As String, remain As String, aTime As String

remaining = span.Hours & "hr:" & span.Minutes & "min:" & span.Seconds & "sec"
remain = span.Hours & span.Minutes & span.Seconds

For y = 0 To remain

    pBar.Minimum = 0
    pBar.Maximum = remain
    pBar.Value = y

    '  MsgBox("Min: " & pBar.Minimum & " Max:" & pBar.Maximum)
    Exit Sub


Next y
```

---

I think I need to put clarification...

I have two times

Alarm Time: 5:00: PM

Current Time: Whatever it may be

I need to calculate the amount of time between the two values and express it in a progress bar as to when the two value will meet as the progress bar will fill up as they near.

Comment: WHYT? (What Have You Tried), show us some code.

Comment: So far I have tried this...

Comment: So far I have tried this...

Comment: Dim span As System.TimeSpan = TimeEnd.TimeOfDay - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        Dim remaining As String, remain As String, aTime As String

        remaining = span.Hours & "hr:" & span.Minutes & "min:" & span.Seconds & "sec"
        remain = span.Hours & span.Minutes & span.Seconds

        For y = 0 To remain

            pBar.Minimum = 0
            pBar.Maximum = remain
            pBar.Value = y

            '  MsgBox("Min: " & pBar.Minimum & " Max:" & pBar.Maximum)
            Exit Sub

        Next y

Answer (score 1):

One of the main issues that you are having is that the ProgressBar requires integers and the Timespan's Hour, Minute and Seconds property just give the integer ie 2 minutes would return 2 whereas it would be 120 seconds so you need to multiply them out to a common resolution in this case I used seconds. I created an example with a DateTimePicker set to Time, a Timer with an interval of 1 second and created a function to give me the difference of two DateTime Objects. See if works for you.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim value As Integer = ProgressBar1.Maximum - GetTimeDifference(DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTime.Now)
        If value > ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ProgressBar1.Value = value

    End Sub

    Public Function GetTimeDifference(EndTime As DateTime, StartTime As DateTime) As Integer
        Dim span As TimeSpan = EndTime.TimeOfDay - StartTime.TimeOfDay
        Dim hour As Integer = span.Hours * 360
        Dim minute As Integer = span.Minutes * 60
        Dim second As Integer = span.Seconds
        Dim result As Integer = hour + minute + second

        Return result

    End Function

End Class
```

Modified Function per Conrads comment:

```
Public Function GetTimeDifference(EndTime As DateTime, StartTime As DateTime) As Integer

    Dim span As TimeSpan = EndTime.TimeOfDay - StartTime.TimeOfDay
    Dim result As Integer = CInt(span.TotalSeconds)

    Return result

End Function
```

Comment: +1 very nice demonstration of what the OP wanted rather than what was wrong with the code snippet although I'm a little confused as to why you didn't go with `span.TotalSeconds` (although it does require conversion from the double to the int)

Comment: @ConradFrix It will work also and be simplier. also It is late :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim span As System.TimeSpan = TimeEnd.TimeOfDay - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
    Dim remaining As String, remain As String, aTime As String

    remaining = span.Hours & "hr:" & span.Minutes & "min:" & span.Seconds & "sec"
    remain = span.Hours & span.Minutes & span.Seconds

    For y = 0 To remain

        pBar.Minimum = 0
        pBar.Maximum = remain
        pBar.Value = y

        '  MsgBox("Min: " & pBar.Minimum & " Max:" & pBar.Maximum)
        Exit Sub


    Next y
```

I am trying to set the pbar.maximum to the remaining time and have it progress as times nears the alarm time.

Comment: l2uLer you should add these codes to your question, not in the answer section mate.